# UIDynamicAnimation issue with autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout, uiviewanimation

I am new to autolayout. 
I have got a view hierarchy working fine with autolayout.

I got a container view displaying a menu. I am animating this view using Dynamics to make a pop effect: the view grows from a tiny size to its target size.

The effect is great. The problem is, since the view needs to be shrink to a tiny tiny size (like 5x5 at the beginning), all the first part of the animation cannot resolve my subviews constraints (like leading AND trailing space cannot be both 10 because the view itself is 10).

I don't care if at this minimum scale the layout is messy or exceeds the view frame but I don't know how to define my constraints to make it work.

Like, is there a way to tell autolayout:

- This trailing space should be 10 but if you can't then ignore it

Or something like that. Since I know which constraint should be ignored it would be great if there is a way to tell it to autolayout instead of having the warning and letting the OS "guess" which constraint to drop.

I am sure I could do everything programmatically by skipping all these constraints before animation, animating, and putting them back but since it is a big table view with many rows there are so many table view cell inner contraints to consider that it would really be hard to achieve.

Any insight / help / pointer on this would be great.

Comment: Could someone please explain to me why he downvoted my question so that I could understand the problem???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This trailing space should be 10 but if you can't then ignore it

The above statement is ambiguous, we need to define when the drawing system needs to add constraint for trailing space to 10 and when to ignore it, specifically.
This is obviously possible through coding it programatically. But,

You can set constraints using inequalities like "greater than or equal to" or "less that or equal to", and that would hopefully solve you problem.

[image]

Comment: So you are suggesting that I define my leading / trailing spaces as less or equal to 10, resulting in the 'optional' behavior I am looking for. I will give it a go and let you know.

Comment: It actually solves everything and works like a charm! As simple as 'less than or equal' (I feel stupid :) Thank you